# Prove this function cannot be continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ such that for every $y$ either there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ or there are exactly two such $x$. We are required to show that $f$ cannot be continuous. I have no idea how to prove this. Also is there a function which satisfies this?

Comment: To find such a function start by noticing that if you have to have two points mapping to the same value then it's probably going to be symmetric about the midpoint of the domain.  That suggests the absolute value function (which probably gives you a hint about the continuity as well).  Try $f(x):=|1/2 -x|$ as a sample function, and then see if that helps you figure out the discontinuous part.

Comment: @postmortes: why should it be symmetric?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but it's an easy place to start to find an exemplar

Answer (score 0):

Because $f$ can have at most one turning point on $[0,\,1]$, it cannot achieve its supremum twice. But by the extreme value theorem, it achieves it at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f$ is continuous. There are 3 cases:

- either $f$ is constant on some interval.  It is not possible because only 2 x are such that $f(x)=y$
- or $f$ change direction at least twice. It is not possible because there would be some $y$ for which there are at least 3 x such that $f(x)=y$
- or $f$ is increasing then decreasing (resp. decreasing then increasing) and the maximum value (resp. minimum) is obtained only for one $x$.

Thus f cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The following should work if $f$ isn't too "pathological".

Assume such an $f$ exists and is continuous. Then the graph of $f$ is connected. Since $f$ cannot be monotonic (then it would be injective), $f$ must change direction in some point $x_0$. But then $f$ has to change direction at least once more: If not, then $y_0=f(x_0)$ is a global extremum, so there is no other $x \neq x_0$ with $f(x)=y_0$, contradicting the assumptions. So $f$ changes directions in some point $x_1 > x_0$ as well, and there is some $x_2 > x_1$ with $f(x_2)=f(x_0)$. But then for some $y \in (f(x_0), f(x_1))$, the equation $f(x) = y$ will have three solutions $x$, which is a contradiction. So no such continuous $f$ can exist.